# How to reshape and interleave matrix elements?

Tags: matlab

Having the values of time sequence, I would like to reshape it into a nx4 matrix [X y], for the purpose of using these values as input and output values for machine learning algorithm.

X(i) is a 1x3 input vector and y is output scalar value.

The algorithm takes as an input every 2nd sequence value (3 values) in order to predict the 4th value.

To give a practical example, let's say we have a sequence

```
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16]
```

The [X y] matrix should be the following:

```
[1 3 5 7; 2 4 6 8; 9 11 13 15; 10 12 14 16]
```

To get every second row I wrote the following code:

```
vec1 = timeSeries(1:2:end);
XyVec1 = reshape(vec1,4,[])'
```

similarly it could be written to get even numbers:

```
vec2 = timeSeries(2:2:end);
XyVec2 = reshape(vec2,5,[])'
```

The thing that I don't know how to do is to interleave matrix vec1 and vec2 rows to get

```
[vec(1,:); vec2(1,:);vec1(2,:), vec2(2,:)...]
```

Does anyone know how to interleave the rows of two (or more) matrices?

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
result = zeros(size(vec1,1)+size(vec2,1),size(vec1,2));
result(1:2:end,:) = vec1;
result(2:2:end,:) = vec2;
```

Reuse matlab indexing facilities ot insert elements in correct rows

Sample octave mock-up: http://ideone.com/RVgmYA

Answer (score 4):

There is this one-liner option

```
result = kron(vec1, [1;0]) + kron(vec2, [0;1]);
```

However, @Joel Falcou is faster. Having set the input vectors as

```
vec1 = rand(1000,1000);
vec2 = -rand(1000,1000);
```

it gives

```
Elapsed time is 0.007620 seconds. (indexing)
Elapsed time is 0.054607 seconds. (kron)
```

Comment: pre-allocate result and i think timign will be roughly equals

Comment: looks like kron is not that optimized then.

Answer (score 2):

Good luck :) figuring out what's going on with those `reshape(), permutes()`:

```
a = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16];
reshape(permute(reshape(a,2,4,[]),[2,1,3]),4,[])'
```

the result

```
ans =
     1     3     5     7
     2     4     6     8
     9    11    13    15
    10    12    14    16
```

Answer (score 1):

To interleave the vectors as mentioned in the end of your question you can use

```
reshape([vec1, vec2]', 4, [])'
```

for

```
vec1 =
     1     3     5     7
     9    11    13    15

vec2 =
     2     4     6     8
    10    12    14    16
```

it returns

```
>> reshape([vec1, vec2]', 4, [])'
ans =
     1     3     5     7
     2     4     6     8
     9    11    13    15
    10    12    14    16
```