# stacking rows of 2 matrices on top of each other consecutively

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I have two matrices, each with about ten rows. I am trying to stack the rows on top of each other consecutively. For example I have matrices A and B, and I have made a for loop to make it repeat the processes of stacking their rows. The problem now is that when I run the script, it only does it for the first row and doesnt continue on. The code is written below

```
A = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10];
B= [11 12 13 14 15 16 171 18 19 20];

for i2= 1:10
      l= A(i2,1);
      p= B(i2,1);
       for i4= 1:10
            i4 = [l;p] ;  
       end
    end
% so the answer will be 
% i4 = [1 11 2 12 3 13 4 14 5 15 6 16 7 17 8 18 9 19 10 20]
```

Please I need some help

Comment: no idea what you are trying to do, need example output. `A(i2,1)` is a single numer, maybe you mean `A(i2,:)`. Dont think you need two loops.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.. i tried it but it didn't change the result, it is still just displaying the first rows of the matrices. i did notice something though in my results.. it is that it saves i2 as 20  `i2 =20` only not as a range between 1 to 20..`i2 =1:20` could anyone pls tell me how to write it so it can give a range?

Comment: well yeah, your second iterator `i4` is overwritten straight away. if you gave a concrete example of what your input and output should we could understand what you are trying to do

Comment: okay so for instance the input could be;`A=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]`   and      ` B =   [ 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20]` so when i run the loop, it will now be ` i4 = [ 1 11 2 12 3 13 4 14 5 15 6 16 7 17 8 18 9 19 10 20]`...

Comment: add it to your question so its easier to read

Comment: First, you have row vectors (1 row, 10 columns), if you want each vector to have 10 rows you must declare them as column vector (use ; so separate elements). Second: Do you want to **stack** or to **interleave** the arrays? Stacking means putting one on top of the other so you will end up with a (2x10) matrix. Interleave means mixing the elements one at a time so you will end with a (1x20) array (which apparently is what your output looks like, but you clearly say "stack the rows on top of each other" which contradicts the output)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't got matlab to test this but:

```
new = []
for i= 1:10
  l= A(i,:);
  p= B(i,:);
  for j= 1:10
        new(end+1) =[l(j),p(j)] ;  
   end
end
```

There is surely a nicer way but this should work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any loops!
just try this:

```
i4 = [A,B];
```

Answer (score 0):

From:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17766565/7252268

```
A = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10];
B= [11 12 13 14 15 16 171 18 19 20];

i4 = zeros(size(A,1), size(A,2)+size(B,2));
i4(:,1:2:end) = A;
i4(:,2:2:end) = B;
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to the solution of Ekin Inceleme you can use

```
i4 = reshape([A.' B.'].', 1, 2*size(A,2));
```

providing that `A` and `B` are equally sized. However, this one here is not so easy to read.

Comment: Yea! IT IS A BIT, BUT IT WORKS TOO! THANK YOU